# Python Image Slicer install failing on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: python, pi-2, ubuntu

I've got a raspberry pi 2 running ubuntu mate. 
It comes pre loaded with python. I attempted to install image_slicer module using

```
pip install image_slicer
```

however I recieve this error dialogue:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-rT06cj/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KmPLrN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rT06cj/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/shawn/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on? I tried the same command to install image_slicer on my mac and it worked fine without error.

Comment: I can add in the .pip debug log file for those who may be interested howerver it is quite extensive (~1300 lines).